# How to sum only digits and filter the string values in rdd pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have rdd like below `rdd=sc.parallelize(['a',3,4,2,'d'])`

i want to sum only digits i.e 3+4+2=9 as output 1  and filter the strings as output2('a','b')

Answer (score 0):

You can filter and reduce the results using regular expressions

```
import re
rdd=spark.sparkContext.parallelize(['a',3,4,2,'d'])

output1 = rdd.filter(lambda x: re.match('\d+$',str(x))).reduce(lambda x,y:x+y)
[out]: 9

output2 = rdd.filter(lambda x: isinstance(x,str)).collect()
[out]: ['a','d']
```